# Merge dataframes rows if fields are in the dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to merge fields if values are in the dictionary.
I have two pandas dataframes:

```
Name    Values
"ABC"   ["A", "B", "C"]
"DEF"   ["D", "E", "F"]
```

and

```
Value  First  Second
"A"    0      5
"B"    2      1
"C"    3      5
"Z"    3      0
```

I would like to get:

```
Name   First   Second
"ABC"  5       11
"Z"    3       0
```

Is there an easy way to make that ? I didn't find something good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `explode` then `map` the key

```
s = df['Value'].map(df2.explode('Values').set_index('Values')['Name'])
out = df.groupby(s).agg({'Name' : ''.join, 'First':'sum', 'Second':'sum'})
```